# How to create an android app that detects all of the device's download?

Tags: android

I need to create an android application that does some work with any file that the device downloads. The problem is that I don't know how to notify my application whenever a download is initiated on the device. I need some way so that either all of the device's downloads are done through my app, or my app gets notified whenever a file is downloaded by the device.
I want to make clear here that I don't want to detect when my application is downloading something, I need to detect each download that the device makes so I can work on the newly downloaded file.

Comment: CommonsWare is right, there's nothing you can do by default, as "download" isn't really a standard event.  Can you describe specifically what you're trying to do to each download?  There may be workarounds.

Comment: I have a way of scanning a file for virus or malwares. What I intended to do was automatically make my app scan the newly downloaded file whenever it detected a download. I gather from both of your replies that specifically doing this is not possible. If I can get some sort of intent when a download is complete, it would suffice.

Comment: The problem with that is that it's up to the downloading app to send out the intent itself... something which third-party apps won't be able to do.  Without root access, there's no way to force any app to share a file that it's downloaded; your only real option is to keep scanning the downloads folder for new items (which not all apps will download to, so it's far from sufficient for a malware prevention app.)

Comment: I understand, I will try to look for another approach for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to create an android application that does some work with any file that the device downloads.

That is not possible for a normal SDK application, as there is no requirement that every app that downloads a file put the file in a place where you can get at it. You *might* be able to pull this off if your app is running as root.

> The problem is that I don't know how to notify my application whenever a download is initiated on the device.

That is not possible, as there is no definition of "download is initiated". Not all Internet traffic represents a downloaded file. Internet traffic represents a downloaded file if and only if the app that used the Internet writes a file that directly represents the bytes received from the Internet. This will be exceptionally difficult to distinguish, as plenty of things (e.g., updating a database) would also involve Internet I/O followed by disk I/O.

> I need some way so that either all of the device's downloads are done through my app

That is not possible, except perhaps on a rooted device if you tinker with firewall settings.